# Why is DataGridView SelectionChanged event not firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In the code below, the `datagridview1_SelectionChanged` event which fires after the selection has been changed through the code in `datagridview1_RowsAdded` event handler, the `CurrentRow` property is null. but I have just set it in `datagridview1_RowsAdded`  handler and it is not null in there.

However, if I comment the two lines in `datagridview1_RowsAdded` handler and select the row through mouse click on any row, the program works fine. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here’s my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
        {
           dataGridView2.Enabled = true;
           dataGridView3.Enabled = true;
           dataGridView4.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
           dataGridView2.Enabled = false;
           dataGridView3.Enabled = false;
           dataGridView4.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView2.Enabled = false;
        dataGridView3.Enabled = false;
        dataGridView4.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question title,it's a bit misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RowsAdded` method, you have selected the current cell but not the current row. You can select the current row with this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Not working cause after the first line in rows_added it goes to selection_changed event before running other lines.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that the CurrentRow property is still null after explicit selection? Try selecting the row before you select the cell.